# Enumeration type comparison error

Tags: c++, gcc, arm

```
typedef enum {
  TYPE_A = 0,
  TYPE_B,
  TYPE_C
} OBJTYPE;
```

Assume there is the enum type above.
I'm using arm-g++ for my working.

And some macro for any type is defined like this:

```
#define ANY_TYPE ((OBJTYPE)-1)
```

But following comparision was false as I tested:

```
if (param->type == ANY_TYPE) something();
else error();
```

param->type was set as ANY_TYPE and its type was OBJTYPE. I logged both of them with '%d' and they were displayed as 255. But it's false and error occurred.

This problem has been not caused from RVCT (commercial arm compiler).
Why does it fail?

Comment: What's wrong with adding `ANY_TYPE = -1` to your enumeration, BTW? Oh, and all-caps identifiers are an indication of a macro.

Comment: I think (OBJTYPE)-1 is interpreted as a subtraction, unlike `(OBJTYPE)(-1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-1 is an illegal value for your enumeration.

The language standard (7.2 Enumeration declarations) says:

> For an enumeration where
>   e<sub>min</sub> is the smallest
>   enumerator and e<sub>max</sub> is the
>   largest, the values of the enumeration
>   are the values of the underlying type
>   in the range b<sub>min</sub> to
>   b<sub>max</sub>, where b<sub>min</sub>
>   and b<sub>max</sub> are, respectively,
>   the smallest and largest values of the
>   smallest bit-field that can store
>   e<sub>min</sub> and e<sub>max</sub>.

According to this, legal values are 0, 1, 2 and 3 (those values that can be represented with two bits). You should add the `ANY_TYPE` enumerator to use it.

Answer (score 0):

> I logged both of them with '%d' and
>   they were displayed as 255. But it's
>   false and error occurred.

Sounds as your compiler assigned ANY_TYPE to param->type as a 8 bit integer. Try using something like

```
#define ANY_TYPE ((OBJTYPE)(int)-1)
```

Or, alternatively, cast both sides of the compare to int.

Comment: How is `(int)` going to help? `-1` will already have type `int`?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use

```
typedef enum {
  ANY_TYPE = -1,
  TYPE_A = 0,
  TYPE_B,
  TYPE_C
} OBJTYPE;
```

I think you wont have that error then.

Comment: Yeah, it's a solution which I already applied. But my question is for finding a reason.